# change default sound of toast notification for windows phone 8.1 app development

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am implementing toast notification for a windows phone 8.1 app using the code below. I have to change the default sound to one which is found in the Assets folder. Can anyone help me please?

```
ToastTemplateType toastType = ToastTemplateType.ToastText02;

                XmlDocument toastXml = ToastNotificationManager.GetTemplateContent(toastType);

                XmlNodeList toastTextElement = toastXml.GetElementsByTagName("text");

                toastTextElement[0].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode("WeCare says: "));
                toastTextElement[1].AppendChild(toastXml.CreateTextNode(initialTime + " seconds left"));

                IXmlNode toastNode = toastXml.SelectSingleNode("/toast");
                XmlElement audio = toastXml.CreateElement("audio");
                // audio.SetAttribute("src", "/Assets/N.mp3");
                ((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("duration", "long");

                //((XmlElement)toastNode).SetAttribute("loop", "true");

                ToastNotification toast = new ToastNotification(toastXml);
                ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(toast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the file you specified in your XML is stored in the proper location. Toast with sound works only on Windows Phone 8 Update 3 and later versions. Also make sure the sound file is less than 10 seconds long.

See this example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Toastproperties)

Make sure your using correct xml format for toast notification

```
public void ShowToastWithCloudService(bool useCustomSound, bool useWavFormat, bool doSilentToast)
{
    StringBuilder toastMessage = new StringBuilder();
    toastMessage.Append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><wp:Notification xmlns:wp=\"WPNotification\"><wp:Toast>");
    toastMessage.Append("<wp:Text1>Toast Title</wp:Text1>");
    toastMessage.Append("<wp:Text2>Toast Content</wp:Text2>");
    if ((IsTargetedVersion) && (useCustomSound))
    {
        if (useWavFormat)
        {
            toastMessage.Append("<wp:Sound>MyToastSound.wav</wp:Sound>");
        }
        else
        {
            toastMessage.Append("<wp:Sound>MyToastSound.mp3</wp:Sound>");
        }
    }
    else if ((IsTargetedVersion) && (doSilentToast))
    {
        toastMessage.Append("<wp:Sound Silent=\"true\"/>");
    }
    toastMessage.Append("</wp:Toast></wp:Notification>");
}
```